# Does Entity Framework(EF5) support XML data type yet?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am thinking of using the XML data type in SQL Server 2008 R2, but also using EF with MVC. Does EF5 support the XML data type? If not then I will have to opt for a different DB design.

Many thanks.

Comment: Having checked this further, I am pretty sure that it does not.

Comment: Unfortunately EF does not support Xml type at the moment.

Comment: Hi Pawel, Could you put this as an answer and then I will mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF does not support Xml type natively at the moment