# Is there an ASP.NET data type equivalent to the XML data type in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to create an app where a user uploads an xml document and that document gets stored in a database column of type "xml". Does anyone know a class equivalent to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `SqlCommand` object to interact with your database, see this from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx):

> For [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) **Xml** enumeration values, you can use a `string`, an `XML` value, an [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) derived type instance, or a [`SqlXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.aspx) object.

If you're using Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework, please refer to these questions:

- [Linq-to-SQL With XML Database Fields -- Why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689772/linq-to-sql-with-xml-database-fields-why-does-this-work)
- [Does Entity Framework(EF5) support XML data type yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031041/does-entity-frameworkef5-support-xml-data-type-yet)